# GTranslate for Joomla showing 400 error and stop working

Tags: joomla, google-translate

I am using GTranslate for Joomla in my Joomla websites. It was working fine. Last day I have observed it stop working, and shows 400 errors in the console (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()).

I found in the console,

"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?[object Map Iterator]=[object Map Iterator]"

Joomla version is, 3.10.1, GTranlator version 3.7.6

Comment: Please ask all of your Joomla-related questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Crossposted on JSE @ [GTranslate for Joomla showing 400 error and stop working](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/31629/12352).  If you have an opinion about crossposting being prohibited, vote @ [Dissonance between allowing signposts and forbidding crossposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371829/352329) to potentially help bring about change.  I will urge anyone with feedback or a solution for this question to contribute to the post @ [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this file "media/system/js/mootools-core.js".
Specifically in this part of the code:

```
Array.from = function(a) {
return null == a ? [] : f.isEnumerable(a) && "string" != typeof a ? "array" == b(a) ? a : e.call(a) : [a]
}
```

Replace with this:

```
old_array_from = Array.from;
Array.from=function(a){
    return null==a
        ?[]
        :f.isEnumerable(a)&&"string"!=typeof a
            ?"array"==b(a)
                ?a
                :e.call(a)
            :("object" == b(a))
                ?old_array_from(a)
                :[a];
};
```

Explaining:

Mootools version 1.4.5 overrides the native 'from' Array method. This causes a conflict with whoever uses Array.from() passing an object as a parameter.

Recently Google's API started to use Array.from passing an object as a parameter. Note that Google Api does not get the expected result in this part of the query string formation: "?[object Map Iterator]=[object Map Iterator]". The formation of the query string was supposed to be something like '...supportedLanguages?client=te&display_language=pt-BR&key=AIzaSyBwiZMn...'

The hack passed above uses javascript's native Array.from when passing an object as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of discussion on this. Some blame Joomla 3.10. I have been in touch with Gtranslate and then they say go to the paid version. I have escalated with them to find a solution, been pursuing this for 6 weeks now. Mootools / Jaquery is the issue i understand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is not Unclear.  Abraham says to upgrade to the paid version of Gtranslate.